# karma, chai with webpack : ERROR [config]: Invalid config file! SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;

Tags: angularjs, webpack, karma-mocha

I'm following an angular-webpack tutorial and when learning testing using karma, webpack was used as the preprocessor in the karma config file, and its entry is set as the watched files for karma : so this is the whole `karma.config.js` :

```
var path = require('path');
var webpackConfig = require('./webpack.config');
var entry = path.resolve(webpackConfig.context, webpackConfig.entry);
var preprocessors = {};
preprocessors[entry] = ['webpack'];

// Karma configuration
// Generated on Wed Sep 14 2016 08:47:45 GMT+0100 (Afr. centrale Ouest)

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',


    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['mocha'],


    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [entry],
    webpack:webpackConfig,


    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [
    ],


    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: preprocessors,


    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress'],


    // web server port
    port: 9876,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,


    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['Chrome'],


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: false,

    // Concurrency level
    // how many browser should be started simultaneous
    concurrency: Infinity,
    plugins:[
        require('karma-webpack'),
        'karma-chai',
        'karma-mocha',
        'karma-chrome-launcher'
    ]
  })
}
```

and this is the `webpack.config.js` required in the previous file :

```
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    context: require('path').resolve(__dirname, "app"),
    entry:'./app.js',
    output: {
        path : __dirname + '/app',
        filename:'bundle.js'
    },
    plugins:[
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            ON_TEST:process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test';
        })
    ],
    module:{
        loaders: [
        {
          test: /\.js$/,
          exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
          loader: 'babel', // 'babel-loader' is also a legal name to reference
          query: {
            presets: ['es2015']
          }
        },
         { test: /\.css$/,
           loader: "style-loader!css-loader",
           exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/
         },
        {
          test: /\.html$/,
          exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
          loader: 'raw', // 'babel-loader' is also a legal name to reference
        },
        {  test: /\.styl$/,
           loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!stylus-loader',
           exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/
         }
      ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx', '.css']
    },
    resolveLoader: {
        root: require('path').resolve(__dirname, "node_modules")
    }
}
```

when i tried to start the karma test i got the following error :

```
$ NODE_ENV=test karma start
14 09 2016 10:54:38.316:ERROR [config]: Invalid config file!
  SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:387:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (M:\Learning webpack\egghead.io - AngularJS - Angular
and Webpack for Modular Applications\webpack-ng-egg\karma.conf.js:2:21)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.parseConfig (M:\Learning webpack\egghead.io - AngularJS - Angular
and Webpack for Modular Applications\webpack-ng-egg\node_modules\karma\lib\confi
g.js:342:22)
    at new Server (M:\Learning webpack\egghead.io - AngularJS - Angular and Webp
ack for Modular Applications\webpack-ng-egg\node_modules\karma\lib\server.js:56:
20)
```

Comment: http://eslint.org/demo/

Comment: thanks but i have tested the karma.config js synthax and there were not errors except require and module were undefined.

Comment: Did you test the other file...?

Comment: not yet but actually i don't know which envirement i should check in the Rules Configuration

Comment: Remove the semicolon on line 12 (after `'test'`).

Comment: yes i did and the error is gone, thanks much

Comment: I am facing the same issue but error is of '{'